# .gql or .graphql file types with Node

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, babeljs

I'm using Apollo's `graphql-server-express` with Node and I would like to turn my "typedef" schema definition files into `.graphql or .gql` files for clarity and syntax highlighting.

What is the best way to do this? I cannot find any good resources online beyond Babel(?) which seems to be the only choice.

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: You can have a directory with all the `.gql` files in it. Load it in Node by reading the files.

Answer (score 24):

I'm sure you found solution so far, but for others this might be helpful 
https://github.com/prismagraphql/graphql-import .

### Usage

```
import { importSchema } from 'graphql-import'
import { makeExecutableSchema } from 'graphql-tools'

const typeDefs = importSchema('schema.graphql')
const resolvers = {}

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers })
```

### Examples

#### Importing specific fields

Assume the following directory structure:

```
.
├── a.graphql
├── b.graphql
└── c.graphql
```

**a.graphql**

```
# import B from "b.graphql"

type A {
  # test 1
  first: String
  second: Float
  b: B
}
```

**b.graphql**

```
# import C from 'c.graphql'

type B {
  c: C
  hello: String!
}
```

**c.graphql**

```
type C {
  id: ID!
}
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.

Comment: package seems to be discontinued

Answer (score 11):

The schemas folder should have files with .graphql or .gql files

```
const path = require('path');
const { loadFilesSync } = require('@graphql-tools/load-files');
const { mergeTypeDefs } = require('@graphql-tools/merge');

const typesArray = loadFilesSync(path.join(__dirname, './schemas'));

module.exports = mergeTypeDefs(typesArray, { all: true });
```

Answer (score 7):

Have a same question how to implement it in right way. Anyway this works for me.

```
import {gql} from 'apollo-server-express'
import * as types from './types.graphql'

export const typeDefs = gql`${types}`
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution for when using `express-graphql` with TypeScript:

```
import {buildSchema} from 'graphql';
import graphqlHTTP from 'express-graphql';
import {importSchema} from 'graphql-import';

import {resolvers} from './graphql/resolvers';

const server = express();

server.use(
  '/graphql',
  graphqlHTTP({
    schema: buildSchema(importSchema('**/*.graphql')),
    rootValue: resolvers,
  }),
);
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same question, and I believe the only way accomplish what you are asking without introducing babel/webpack into your server-side pipeline is to write you query as an exported template string.

e.g.

```
/* query.gql */
module.exports = `
schema {
  query: Query
  mutation: Mutation
}

type Query {
  posts: [Post]
  post(id:String, slug:String): Post
  user(uid:String): User
}
...
`
```

Thankfully, VS Code syntax highlighters for GraphQL support this method.